# Is there a more elegant way to get specific value from JSON object using system.text.json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Consider this Json object:

```
{
    "main": {
        "2058": {
            "id": "2058",
            "name": "foo",
            "attrib1": "17",
            "domain": "somewhere.net",
            "enabled": "1",
            "permissions": [
                "admin",
                "user",
                "guest",
                "vpn",
                "power"
            ]
        }
    },
    "validate": {
        "2058": {
            "id": "2058",
            "name": "foo",
            "attrib1": "17",
            "domain": "somewhere.net",
            "enabled": "1",
            "permissions": [
                "admin",
                "user",
                "guest",
                "vpn",
                "power"
            ]
        }
    },
    "result": "ok"
}
```

Between "enabled" and "permissions", there are quite a few hundred more pairs witch i left out. The "validate" part is an exact copy of "main" and the "result" is, well ya, the result.

I want to get 2 specific values from the main section. "id" and "domain". I use the following code to do so.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace JsonParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string json = "{" +
                "\"main\":{" +
                    "\"2058\":{" +
                        "\"id\":\"2058\"," +
                        "\"name\":\"foo\"," +
                        "\"attrib1\":\"17\"," +
                        "\"domain\":\"somewhere.net\"," +
                        "\"enabled\":\"1\"," +
                        "\"permissions\":[\"admin\",\"user\",\"guest\",\"vpn\",\"power\"]" +
                    "}" +
                "}," +
                "\"validate\":{" +
                    "\"2058\":{" +
                        "\"id\":\"2058\"," +
                        "\"name\":\"foo\"," +
                        "\"attrib1\":\"17\"," +
                        "\"domain\":\"somewhere.net\"," +
                        "\"enabled\":\"1\"," +
                        "\"permissions\":[\"admin\",\"user\",\"guest\",\"vpn\",\"power\"]" +
                    "}" +
                "}," +
                "\"result\":\"ok\"" +
            "}";

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json))
            {
                if (item.Key == "main")
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> pairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(item.Value.ToString());
                    Dictionary<string, object> pairs1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(pairs.First().Value.ToString());
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> valuePair in pairs1)
                    {
                        if (valuePair.Key == "id" || valuePair.Key == "domain")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + valuePair.Key + "\nValue: " + valuePair.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this, i get "2058" and "somewhere.net" but is there are more elegant way to get the values instead of deserialize 3 times?

Comment: Here's a tracking issue for JsonPath support in the framework. This would be a good solution when available. Unfortunately pushed off until at least .NET 6. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31068

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `System.Text.Json` API, you can parse your JSON to [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1) first, then enumerate its properties. Get the `main` object first, then flatten its child properties and find required values by `id` and `domain` names

```cs
using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);

var main = document.RootElement.EnumerateObject().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "main");
var properties = main.Value.EnumerateObject().SelectMany(p => p.Value.EnumerateObject()).ToList();
var id = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "id").Value.GetString();
var domain = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "domain").Value.GetString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the `main` property you can use [json path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) to select all "mains" via Newtonsoft Json.NET:

```
var pairs = JObject.Parse(js).SelectTokens("$.main.*")
    .Select(j => (id:j["id"],domain: j["domain"]))
    .ToList();
```

or just deserialize to corresponding structure (either with `System.Text.Json` or Newtonsoft):

```
class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, InnerClass> main { get; set; }
}

class InnerClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
}

ICollection<InnerClass> mains= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(js).main.Values; // System.Text.Json
```

Comment: OP is using `system.text.json`